# Configure relationships with SwiftData in Preview

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-data, swift-data-relationship

We are developing an iOS app using SwiftData. We have `Bucket` and `BucketItem` models where a `Bucket` can have many `BucketItem`, so there is a relationship between `Bucket` and `BucketItem`. Below is a simplified version of the models.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftData

@Model
class Bucket {
  var name: String
  var shared: Bool
  
  @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade, inverse: \BucketItem.bucket) var items = [BucketItem]()
  
  init(name: String, shared: Bool) {
    self.name = name
    self.shared = shared
  }
}
```

---

```
import Foundation
import SwiftData

@Model
class BucketItem {
  var content: String
  var bucket: Bucket
  
  init(content: String, bucket: Bucket) {
    self.content = content
    self.bucket = bucket
  }
}
```

We show a list of `Bucket` with a count of how many `BucketItem` it has. This is working in the app on the device and simulator, however the relationship is not working on the Preview. Below is a simplified version of this component with the Preview configuration

```
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct BucketsData: View {
 var bucket: Bucket //this is provided by a parent component that uses @Query to fetch the Buckets
  
  var body: some View {
    List {
      Section(bucket.name) {
        Text("Items: \(bucket.items.count)")
      }
      
    }
  }
}

#Preview {
  let config = ModelConfiguration(isStoredInMemoryOnly: true)
  let container = try! ModelContainer(for: Bucket.self, configurations: config)
  
  let testBucket = Bucket(name: "Test Bucket", shared: true)
  container.mainContext.insert(testBucket)
  
  let testItem = BucketItem(content: "Test Item", bucket: testBucket)
  container.mainContext.insert(testItem)
  
  return BucketsData(bucket: testBucket)
    .modelContainer(container)
}
```

The list show the "Test Bucket" with a count of 0 items. It appears that for some reason the `items` array is not getting populated with the related `BucketItem`. How can we fix this?

Comment: You insert `testBucket` twice and `testItem` zero times.

Comment: @Paulw11 you're right, I pasted the wrong version of the simplified component. I updated the example above.

Comment: You can fix this issue with a single character but I suspect you don't want to apply that fix. Make the `bucket` property optional in `BucketItem` and the preview will work fine without any other changes. I tried to find some other way to solve this but without success.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson it works, thank you. Actually I've seen another scenario where SwiftData works the way you would expect only if you set one side of the relationship as optional. It appears that for some reason SwiftData requires that to be fully functional, hopefully Apple will fix that in the future.